# data to image reactJS

Tags: image, reactjs

I'm trying to retrieve a picture from my API, I'm sending the data like this :

```js
router.post('/loadpicture', function(req, res, next) {
  var imgPath = __dirname + "/no_photo.png";
  // var imgPath = __dirname + "/photototo.jpg";
  fs.access(imgPath, fs.F_OK, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      else {
        res.sendFile(imgPath, (err) => { if (err) next(err); });
      }
    });
  })
```

And I'm trying to display the picture like this:

```js
        var url = "data:image/png;base64,"+this.props.picture;

        return (
          <div>
          <h1>Change your profile pictures</h1>
            <img src={url} alt={'hello'}/>
          </div>
        );
```

But here is the result:

[image: Result]

I don't know what can I do.. I tried to remove newlines and other spaces 
with `url.replace(/\s+/g, '')` but it's not working.

**UPDATE:** I just replaced with this and it works :

```js
router.post('/loadpicture', function(req, res, next) {
  var imgPath = __dirname + "/no_photo.png";
  var img = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
  res.end(img.toString('base64'));
  })
```

Comment: could you post the value of `this.props.picture`

Comment: @AakashSigdel something like this: http://imgur.com/a/KRVJr